# Message sent to deallocated instance after heavy use?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am testing an app provided by a third party developer and finding that I'm getting a seemingly random "message sent to deallocated instance 0xeb2f0d0" message after heavy use of the app. It's normally when returning back into a menu

It comes from the class Locationmap, which seems to deallocate correctly at the end:

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
```

// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

For the life of me, I can't understand why it would only happen after heavy use - any ideas?

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 0):

You might check if a Memory Warning causes your object to be released - you can simulate that in the simulator. Not-on-screen views/controllers might unload their data in that case. If this is a problem, your *real* problem is that you don't initialize your objects accordingly (but rely on a warning not to happen - which becomes more and more speculative with multitasking).

Comment: Thanks for your response Eiko, I just tried this. The first two times the memory warning killed it instantly with the same error message (but different classes). However, the next two times it coped with it. I have noticed that if I reset the iPhone simulator and try again I get a lot longer to play before it happens -- sounds like a memory issue, right?

Comment: Yes - but it is your responsibility to handle those cases. You can choose to *not* unload your view/viewcontroller in case of a memory warning (check Apple's documentation, I don't have the example at hand). This might not be recommended, but works as a temporary solution. If you experience memory problems after heavy use though, this indicates a memory leak, and you should investigate with Instruments.